# Discord bot won't come online unless it is Administrator

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am playing with my first discord bot, but have been unable to get it to read any messages. I looked through several tutorials, and all of them are using the `Administrator` privilege for convenience. However, I would like to restrict the bot's permissions, as I only want to read/send messages and maybe send some emojis.

When I select only permissions pertaining to sending texts and emojis, I noticed that the bot isn't even listed in the `Online` section in the Discord app on the right. HOWEVER, if I add in the Administrator permission, suddenly the bot is seen online, and will correctly read/send messages.

Here is what I have:

I have created my own server, with me as the only member and I am administrator (I have a crown next to my username in the Online section).

My Bot permissions (set through Discord's Oauth web page):
[image]

When I go to the Discord App and `Server settings -> Integrations -> <role_name>`, I see my bot, and it shows:

[image]

Not sure why there are different permissions set on the Role vs what I set through the Discord OAuth web page though.

The code is super simple:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run('<key>')
```

On running the script, I do see the message:

```
We have logged in as mytest_bot#9274
```

So it is connected and working, but the bot just isn't online. In fact, if I add in ALL Permissions EXCEPT Administrator, the bot still WON'T come online:
[image]

It's ONLY when I set the bot to Administrator that the bot then **magically** comes online and starts processing the `on_message()` code.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The bot is online but it seems like you have *private* channels that only people/roles allowed can see. Having an administrator bypasses channel permissions that allow you to see the channel thus being on the member list.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the bot on your server has the same name and client-id like the bot from your token in the bot file.

Comment: They are the same

Comment: Try adding an bot-activity for the on_ready event. Something like this:
`await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(f'Coding'), status=discord.Status.online)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a command. :-

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test")
```